# What does this callback function do?

Tags: c++, opencv

So I started to develope an OpenCV program and the thing is that I don't know what this segment of code do in the whole context. Below is an abstract version of the whole code.

```
class foo{
private:
    friend void callBack(void *param);
    void draw(void);
public:
    void func(void);
    void update(void);
}

void callBack(void *param){
    foo *context = static_cast<foo*>(param);
    if(context){
        context->draw();
    }
}

foo::foo(std::string windowName){
    cv::namedWindow(windowName, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);
    cv::resizeWindow(windowName, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);
    cv::setOpenGlContext(windowName);
    cv::setOpenGlDrawCallback(windowName, callBack, this);
}

void foo::func(void){
    cv::updateWindow(m_windowName);
}

void draw(void){
    //implementation shows here!!
}
```

You don't have to explain all the code here. All I need to know is the part where static casting happens. What does it do? Why does a person who implements the code write it this way?

Comment: That is the usual pattern to interface with a C-library callback mechanism. The callback is registered with a pointer to user data (which is the object pointer in this case)

Comment: I know what callback function is and how does it works. The thing I want to ask is the reason why they used static_cast<foo*> param. Does this create new class and replace the one that has been existed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d24/group__highgui__opengl.html) of [`cv::setOpenGlDrawCallback`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d24/group__highgui__opengl.html#gaf80dcbc168a6ce40f6d1ad9d79a10bb8)

The signature is:

```
void cv::setOpenGlDrawCallback(const String& winname,
                               OpenGlDrawCallback onOpenGlDraw,
                               void* userdata = 0 
                              )
```

The `OpenGLDrawCallback` is a function pointer of type `void (void* arg)`: where `arg` is any pointer type you pass to it. In this case, OpenCV actually passes `userdata` to it. See [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) *(still applicable to C++)*

```
cv::setOpenGlDrawCallback(windowName, callBack, this);
```

In your code, passing `this` implicitly converted *(a copy of the pointer)* it to `void*` and held by `userdata` . And and `callback` is called to draw on your frame

> All I need to know is the part where static casting happens. What does
>   it do? Why does a person who implements the code write it this way?

```
void callBack(void *param){
    foo *context = static_cast<foo*>(param);
    if(context){
        context->draw();
    }
}
```

The casting converts the void pointer, `param` to an object of type `foo`. it basically gets back the semantics of `this` that was casted when you passed it as a void pointer.